# Accessing serial port in kernel module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, serial-port

I want to access the pins of my com port on my linux machine. 
This is possible with the kernel function call outb/inb.

I tried the following:

```
#define COM1_BASE_ADDRESS 0x3F8

unsigned char reg = inb((unsigned char)(COM1_BASE_ADDRESS + UART_MCR));
printk(KERN_INFO "MCR register: 0x%X\n", reg);

reg = 1;
printk(KERN_INFO "MCR register to write: 0x%X\n", reg);
outb(reg, (unsigned char)(COM1_BASE_ADDRESS + UART_MCR)); 

reg = inb((unsigned char)(COM1_BASE_ADDRESS + UART_MCR));
printk(KERN_INFO "MCR register: 0x%X\n", reg);
```

The kernel module itself should work properly, as i get the kernel messages in my kernel log (dmesg).
But for some reason the register i want to write, doesn't change.
inb always returns 0xFF for the given address.

Do i need something like allocating i/o memory for my process?

Comment: Not sure, but in `outb((unsigned char)(COM1_BASE_ADDRESS + UART_MCR), reg);` you set the register and then print it. Shouldn't you first read it back with `inb`?

Comment: sorry, forgot to add the line. The reg, and port param was also wrong in outb function. But still same problem

Comment: Your solution is racy with the running driver of UART. I would recommend to consider either do stuff in user space, or do the slave driver for UART, like Bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to it was to remove the `unsigned char` cast in the parameter list of `inb` and `outb`.